# Exception thrown at 0x00007FFC0B57BCEF (swscale-6.dll) in App.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

Tags: opencv, visual-c++, ffmpeg

Trying to play a video using FFmpeg on visual studio 2022 on windows 10.
Exception is thrown at sws_scale in the code. Don't know why this is occurred.
It is worth noting that this error sometimes occurs when reading the camera and sometimes it does not.

here is my code

```
bool CalibrationPanel::video_reader_read_frame(VReaderState* state, cv::Mat cvimg)
{
    // Unpack members of state
    auto& width = state->width;
    auto& height = state->height;
    auto& av_format_ctx = state->av_format_ctx;
    auto& av_codec_ctx = state->av_codec_ctx;
    auto& video_stream_index = state->video_stream_index;
    auto& av_frame = state->av_frame;
    auto& av_packet = state->av_packet;
    auto& sws_scaler_ctx = state->sws_scaler_ctx;


    // Decode one frame
    int response;
    while (av_read_frame(av_format_ctx, av_packet) >= 0)
    {
        if (av_packet->stream_index != video_stream_index)
        {
            av_packet_unref(av_packet);
            continue;
        }

        response = avcodec_send_packet(av_codec_ctx, av_packet);
        if (response < 0)
        {
            char errStr[256] = {0};
            av_strerror(response, errStr, sizeof(errStr));
            printf("Failed to decode packet: %s\n", errStr);
            return false;
        }

        response = avcodec_receive_frame(av_codec_ctx, av_frame);
        if (response == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || response == AVERROR_EOF)
        {
            av_packet_unref(av_packet);
            continue;
        }
        else if (response < 0)
        {
            char errStr[256] = {0};
            av_strerror(response, errStr, sizeof(errStr));
            printf("Failed to decode packet: %s\n", errStr);
            return false;
        }

        av_packet_unref(av_packet);
        break;
    }
    int64_t* pts = &ppts;
    *pts = av_frame->pts;

    // Set up sws scaler
    if (!sws_scaler_ctx)
    {
        sws_scaler_ctx = sws_getContext(width, height, av_codec_ctx->pix_fmt,
                                        width, height, AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24,
                                        SWS_BILINEAR, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (!sws_scaler_ctx)
        {
            printf("Couldn't initialize sw scaler\n");
            return false;
        }
    }


    // Creating an image space to hold YUV images
    AVFrame* frameYUV = av_frame_alloc();
    auto* out_buffer = (unsigned char*)av_malloc(av_image_get_buffer_size(AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, width, height, 1));
    av_image_fill_arrays(frameYUV->data, frameYUV->linesize, (const uint8_t*)out_buffer, AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, width, height, 1);

    uint8_t* dest[4] = {cvimg.data, NULL, NULL, NULL};
    sws_scale(sws_scaler_ctx, av_frame->data, av_frame->linesize, 0, av_frame->height, dest, frameYUV->linesize);

    return true;
}
```

fixed this bug, so it's not luck that makes the camera turn on every time.